# i want to play this video for 5sec after that is pause till 10sec then again resume and play till 15 sec but only above if condtion is working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $video = $('#vid1');
        var video = $video.get(0);

        video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
            var lastCheckedAt = $video.data('lastcheck') || 0;
            $video.data('lastcheck', this.currentTime);

            if (this.currentTime >= 5 && lastCheckedAt < 5) {
                console.log('5 seconds');
                this.pause();
                $('#landingpage1').show();
            } else if (this.currentTime >= 10 && lastCheckedAt < 10) {
                console.log('10 seconds');
                this.play();
                $('#landingpage1').hide();
            } else if (this.currentTime >= 15 && lastCheckedAt < 15) {
                console.log('15 seconds');
                this.pause();
            }
        });
    });
```

i want to play this video for 5sec after that is pause till 10sec then again resume and play till 15 sec but only above if condtion is working.

Comment: What's your question? Please see [ask] for tips.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: While the video is paused, video.currentTime doesn't change.

Comment: I can't see anywhere that you are waiting for realtime 10 seconds to pass. Do you need to use setTimeout for example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is, but here are two options:

1. Play video for 5 realtime seconds, pause and wait 10 realtime seconds, then play for another 5 realtime seconds:

```js
async function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

$(document).ready(async function() {
        var $video = $('#vid1');
        var video = $video.get(0);

        await video.play();

        await wait(5 * 1000);

        await video.pause();

        await wait(10 * 1000);

        await video.play();

        await wait(5 * 1000);

        await video.pause();
    });
```

2. Play the video until it reaches duration 5 seconds, skip to duration 15 seconds, then stop at duration 20 seconds:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $video = $('#vid1');
        var video = $video.get(0);

        video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
            if (this.currentTime >= 5 && this.currentTime < 15) {
                console.log('between 5 and 15 seconds');
                this.currentTime = 15; // Skip to 15 seconds.
            } else if (this.currentTime >= 20) {
                console.log('20 seconds have passed.');
                this.pause();
            }
        });
    });
```